# Somehow this won't show me an alert or any errors

Tags: javascript

somehow this code just blanks and isn't really doing anything.
Doesn't even show any errors.
So can Someone help?

```
function connectStart(mycon){ //connection start for contacting 
    return function(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var jsonReturn = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        mycon; //calls the makeAnn() Function

        }
    };
// mypref() stands for the preference code location for the myphp.php
xmlhttp.open("GET", mypref()+"myphp.php?q="+myvar,true);
xmlhttp.send();
        }
}

function makeAnn(){
    return function(){
    console.log(jsonReturn);
    if ( jsonReturn !== "NO"){
            alert("Announcement Was Posted");
    } else {
        alert("Error Encoding Data");
    }
        } //end of return function()
}

function mainFunction(){ //is called by an onclick event
var myvar = "I Shall Return!";
connectStart(makeAnn()); // i used invocation to combine them
}
```

Somehow it never shows any actual complaints or anything on the console log.
No alerts or whatever.
Doesn't write the data sent to the php or database.
No nothing really.
And I have tried the Php and html, their both fine.
It's just this part of my code that won't work.

Comment: When are you calling `mainFunction()`..? If this is all your code, you arent calling any of it. Also please format correctly, very hard to read. Ideally please create a fiddle or similar so we can see this happening. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there's no "php" here

Comment: just finished editing

Comment: @DanielBrose there is a php file involved and it is not online for the world to see. Sorry don't have a router.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what do you mean *no php here* ?

Comment: `mycon; //calls the makeAnn() Function` no it doesn't. If you want to do that, you need to pass makeAnne **without** brackets and then put brackets here instead...

Comment: @Arkonsol you have only posted javascript code

Comment: the php and the html has no problem because the html only calls it, and i have tried the php and it works fine. and @shadow I used the invocation method on them...

Comment: all you posted was js. If you've no php, the tag should be removed

Comment: I believe @shadow's comment is on the right track, except with how you have written this, with `makeAnn()` returning a function, you should leave the `connectStart(makeAnn())` as it is, but change the `mycon;` line inside of `connectStart` to `mycon();` so it invokes the function created by `makeAnn()`

Comment: I edited the question to remove the php tag, but Arkonsol put it back for some reason.

Comment: wops, sorry didn't realize it was the tag change :/

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function inside your `onreadystatechange` handler. See below.

```
function connectStart(mycon){ //connection start for contacting 
    return function(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var jsonReturn = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        // mycon; //wouldn't do anything
           mycon(); // THIS should work better...
        }
    };
    // mypref() stands for the preference code location for the myphp.php
    xmlhttp.open("GET", mypref()+"myphp.php?q="+myvar,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The other problem which I now noticed is that you are referencing `jsonReturn` way, way out of its scope.

```
function connectStart(mycon){ //connection start for contacting 
    return function(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var jsonReturn = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        mycon(jsonReturn); // pass jsonReturn as a parameter

        }
    };
// mypref() stands for the preference code location for the myphp.php
xmlhttp.open("GET", mypref()+"myphp.php?q="+myvar,true);
xmlhttp.send();
        }
}

function makeAnn(){
    return function(jsonReturn){ // pass in as a parameter

    console.log(jsonReturn);
    if ( jsonReturn !== "NO"){
            alert("Announcement Was Posted");
    } else {
        alert("Error Encoding Data");
    }
        } //end of return function()
}

function mainFunction(){ //is called by an onclick event
var myvar = "I Shall Return!";
connectStart(makeAnn()); // i used invocation to combine them
}
```

Comment: And you are certain (from looking in your browser's devtools) that the HTTP request is returning? Sorry I see another issue now as well.

Comment: @Arkonsol please see updated answer. You were also trying to reference `jsonReturn` out of its scope.